# How do combine two Queries or is it only one?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-13

**Question:**

How do combine two Queries or is it only one?

**Example:**

I have two exact similar tables my PostgreSQL Database. `info_table` and `info_table_dump` with the exact same columns `date_at`, `name`, `color` and `length` . Now i want to know if there are entries in `info_table_dump` that do not exist in `info_table`. Therefore i made these Query:

```
SELECT
date_at,name,color,length
FROM
info_table_dump
EXCEPT
SELECT
date_at,name,color,length
FROM
info_table;
```

The result is fine. It works like i assumed (i created 2 entries that do not match) the none-duplicates are shown. But now i wanted only to fetch the given `id`s of the non-duplicate rows. Something like this...

```
SELECT
id
FROM
info_table_dump
WHERE
(SELECT
date_at,name,color,length
FROM
info_table_dump
EXCEPT
SELECT
date_at,name,color,length
FROM
info_table);
```

I also tried something with `EXISTS` but its not the result i wanted.

So my Question how do combine the Query?

I want only the `ìd`s of the `info_table_dump` rows, who not already exist in `info_table`.

Comment: `SELECT id FROM info_table_dump where (date_at,name,color,length) not in
(SELECT date_at,name,color,length FROM info_table)` Can't remember how nulls are handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So they should not exist in info_table?

```
SELECT id
FROM info_table_dump d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM info_table i
  WHERE i.date_at IS NOT DISTINCT FROM d.date_at
    AND i.name IS NOT DISTINCT FROM d.name
    AND i.color IS NOT DISTINCT FROM d.color
    AND i.length IS NOT DISTINCT FROM d.length
);
```

The [IS NOT DISTINCT FROM](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Is_distinct_from) is just in case some columns are nullable.

A more conventional old-school method would be a left join and filtering the unmatched.  Which might actually have better performance.

```
SELECT d.id
FROM info_table_dump d
LEFT JOIN info_table i
  ON i.date_at IS NOT DISTINCT FROM d.date_at
 AND i.name IS NOT DISTINCT FROM d.name
 AND i.color IS NOT DISTINCT FROM d.color
 AND i.length IS NOT DISTINCT FROM d.length
WHERE i.id IS NULL;
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=aa09661a09cc0c06080b8b6936edbfa8)*

Comment: Thanks. It Worked. I just do not understand that `SELECT 1` line. if you have some link for further reading i would appreciate that.

Comment: [Here's a link](https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/exists.php) Basically, it doesn't matter if it's `SELECT 1` or `SELECT *` or `SELECT 'WTF'`. What matters is, if it can find at least 1 match.